# SQL Server - Use substring in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to come up with a query in which it's going to filter based on a substring.
The substring operation is working fine if I use it as a select statement, but not when I try to use it for filtering

```
-- These are some examples of the data I have
--cust_12
--cust_123
--temp_db
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,8,LEN(name)) AS ClientId, name FROM sys.databases
WHERE SUBSTRING(name,8,LEN(name)) IN ('12, 123');
```

If I run the query without the where section, the data is parsed correctly, however when using the where I got no results

Comment: With your logic, the string "cust_12" is evaluated as '' - you start at the 8th character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the logic you want?

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(name, 8, LEN(name)) IN ('12', '123')
```

But I think I would be more inclined to write this as:

```
where name like '%[_]12'] or
      name like '%[_]123'
```

I just think the intent is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are wrong:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,8,LEN(name)) AS ClientId, name FROM sys.databases
WHERE SUBSTRING(name,8,LEN(name)) IN ('12, 123');
```

should be:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,8,LEN(name)) AS ClientId, name FROM sys.databases
WHERE SUBSTRING(name,8,LEN(name)) IN ('12', '123');
```